# How to send cucumber html report on mail

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins

I have automation project which i'm running through Jenkins . With build successful or failure all html reports are being displayed after i click on link "Cucumber Feature Level Overview Report" .

Added dependency in pom

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>email-ext</artifactId>
<version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Added code in jenkins job :-
Section : Editable Email Notification -> Default Content

${FILE,path="https://jenkins.company.com/dareProject/job/Automation_Jobs/job/Dare_Project_job/Cucumber_Steps_Level_Overview_Report/"}

The mail which i'm getting with error :-

ERROR: File 'https://jenkins.company.com/dareProject/job/Automation_Jobs/job/Dare_Project_job/Cucumber_Steps_Level_Overview_Report/' does not exist

And how to display report in Body Text of email ?

Answer (score 0):

> The mail which i'm getting with error

In `path` parameter you must use the location of file in filesystem relative to job's workspace, not the hyperlink to it!

> And how to display report in Body Text of email ?

Set correct path in `Default Content` field and choose `HTML (text/html)` in `Content Type` field.